# GIMP picture loses transparency when i put it in HTML

Tags: html, css, transparency

i am creating a Rock Paper Scissors game for The Odin Project.What i want to do is: instead of click buttons to do the choice, i want to put circular pictures of Rock/Paper/Scissors and click these to make the choice.
I found some pictures online, so i was trying to find a way to crop them in a circular way, and the background to be transparent.
I found online that a tool to do this, is GIMP. I did everything correctly there, the picture has this gray-grid background, but still when i put the picture on the html, still is shown as a square with white background.

This is what i see in GIMP:
[image]

and this is what i get on HTML:
[image].

I am doing everything correctly on GIMP and also i am exporting the picture to .png .

Any help would be highly appreciated

in GIMP, i added an Alpha channel, i did the crop, the background was transparent there, i exported the file as a .png (clicked "Do not save background colour), and still the picture doesn't appear transparent

Comment: Could you provide your HTML/CSS code ?

Comment: Is the picture transparent when you open in in the browser (as opposed to linking it from HTML)? Does browser inspector reveal any unexpected background colour being assigned?

Comment: when i open the picture on Chrome, i still see a square picture with white background.
I inspect it and see the following:

    element.style {
    display: block;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
    transition: background-color 300ms;
}

if i disable the background color line, it appears as a circle, just like i want it

Comment: How are you doing the "put the picture on the html" part? Can you add an HTML example? (It might be some part of your HTML that has a background rather than the image)

Comment: ` <button id='rock' class="btn btn-square"> <img src="./img/13141312.png" alt="Rock" style="background: transparent;"></button>`

Comment: Browser styles can make it tricky to figure out if the image is indeed transparent, but changing `background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);` to anything else (`background-color: blue;`) should make it clear. If the picture is OK, then inspect CSS applied **in your HTML document** (rather than Chrome view picture page).

Comment: If your image is inside a button, it's almost certainly the button that's giving it a background. If you can add a complete HTML/CSS example to the question we might be able to help properly.

Comment: You are totally right, and that why that was happening to me.
In the end, the picture was totally fine, and the background was transparent.

I am totally a beginner in HTML/CSS/JS and what i did is that i tried to put the picture inside the button. 
Instead, i used the following:
<input type='image' blablablabla>

and everything worked correctly. 

Thank you very much for your help! All of you!